# Useful data structure for the following case

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

Which can be the beste data structures for the following case.

1.Should have operations like search, insert and delete. Mostly searching activities will be there.Around 90% of the operations will be search and rest are delete and insert.

2 Insertion,deletion and searching will  be based on the  key of the objects. Each key will point to a object. The keys will be sorted.

Any suggestion for optimal data structure will be highly appreciated.

Comment: "optimal"?  What do you want to optimize?  Time?  Memory use?  Lines of code?

Comment: @S.Lott, there is a rule of thumb where I come from, when in doubt, "optimal" is a measure of alliteration, and therefore a linked list is usually the correct answer.

Comment: What do you mean by "the keys will be sorted"? They come in in sorted order? You want to iterate over them in sorted order?

Comment: @davin: Good point.  I spent a long time working for "Big, In-House IT" where optimal means "uses the RDBMS we already license".  I couldn't square that with the question very well.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Some idea in data structure](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5920579/some-idea-in-data-structure)

Answer (score 1):

AVL tree, or at least BST.

If you want to acces often the same elements you might want to consider splay trees too.

(Should I explain why?)

Comment: Both these AVL and Splay trees are quite good for memory structures, but tend to perform poorly (or hard to implement optimally) on disk.  For block-oriented media, B*tree is hard to beat

Comment: AVL trees have a guaranteed complexity of O(log n) for the three operations but are quite hard to implement correctly (well there are a lot of good examples on the net). Splay trees are AVL trees that are designed so that the last accessed element of the structure is put at the root of the tree (so is accessible in O(1)) It is best used when you often search for the same things because things accessed recently stays near the top.

Answer (score 1):

*Not sure by what you mean with "data structures"*

I would suggest [MySQL](http://www.mysql.com/).
Read more here: [WikiPedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL)

Comment: By data structures he most likely means an in-memory structure like an array, list, dictionary, tree, heap, etc.

Comment: Oh okay cool! I thought that. But when he mentioned the "operations", I thought DB. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Self-balancing tree of sorts (AVL, RB), or a hash table.

Answer (score 1):

My guess is that you want to optimize time. Overall, a [red-black tree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Red-black_tree) will have logarithmic-time performance in all three operations. It will probably be your best overall bet on execution time; however, red-black trees are complex to implement and require a node structure meaning they will be stored using more memory than the contained data itself requires.

Comment: There are really few data structures that doesn't use more memory than the data itself.

Answer (score 1):

You want a tree-backed Map; basically you just want a tree where the nodes are dynamically sorted ("self-balanced") by key, with your objects hanging off of each node with corresponding key.

If you would like an "optimal" data structure, that completely depends on the distribution of patterns of inputs you expect. The nice thing about a self-balancing tree is you don't really need to care too much about the pattern of inputs. If you really want the best-guess as-close-to-optimal as possible we know of, and you don't know much about the specific sequences of queries, you can use a http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tango_tree which is `O(log(log(N))`-competitive. This grows so slowly that, for all practical purposes, you have something which performs no worse than effectively a constant factor from the best possible data structure you could have chosen.

However it's somewhat grungy to implement, you may just be better using a library for a self-balancing tree.

Python:
https://github.com/pgrafov/python-avl-tree/

Java:
If you're just Java, just use a `TreeMap` (red-black tree based) and ignore the implementation details. Most languages have similar data structures in their standard libraries.

Comment: But i came to know from wikipedia article that it does not support deletion and insertion. Useful for static data only. But i need those  deletion and insertion operations too.

Comment: Sorry, it seems my edit didn't go through before your comment: Depending on your language, there are many tools that do what you want. I gave examples for Python and Java.